# To inherit or not to inherit? Some professional opinions wanted

Tags: c#, asp.net, oop, inheritance, code-first

I am designing a C# ASP.Net web application that uses a lot of common functionality and the right way to deal with that seems to be through inheritence. I plan to make a base class (Person) and the inherit it in other classes like Employee and Vendor, and then in turn inherit Employee with Manager, etc. That way I don't have to define common properties such as FirstName, LastName, PhoneNumber, etc. on each one of them.

The second part of the questions is this: If I use inheritence and use Entity Framework's CodeFirst entities, will they understand the inheritence? How will the data be stored in the tables? Will each table have a FirstName and LastName column, or is EF smart enough to make them a common table?

I am really hoping someone who is a REAL object oriented programmer out there can help me clear this up. I have gotten a lot of conficting information and I need someone with actual experience on EF projects to give me some guidance. Am I understanding inheritence right? If not, what am I getting wrong? Any help is appreciated.

Thanks,

Bert

Comment: For the Database choice both choices you mentioned are valid, but some prefer duplicate common data in many tables other will create one table that will hold common data and other tables related to it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not an easy question, but for most cases it's better to choose composition instead of inheritance. You should not derive cash dispenser from calculator just because calculator has display and keyboard properties. It's ridiculous.
But sometimes inheritance makes sense. Ask yourself, should those classes have 'is a' relationship? As I see your task, it's better to make Vendor and Employee to be independent classes, both have Person property. And derive Manager from Employee.
Nevertheless keep depth of inheritance as little as possible. Deep hierarchies are pain to debug and understand, especially if there are many method overrides. 
For more inspiration about the topic have a look at [Chad Myers blogpost](http://lostechies.com/chadmyers/2010/02/13/composition-versus-inheritance/).

Answer (score 1):

First 1: Sounds good. But make sure that an "is a"-relation is given. Do not derive Person from Address just to include the Address-specific properties - use EF complex types for this kind of reuse.

One issue that comes to my mind: Are you sure that `Vendor` is a sub type of `Person`?

More on that: make sure that you stay within "one domain" with your inheritance. As Vinny posted in another possible answer, if the same Person could be Manager AND CustomerContact and both inherit from Person you run into a problem. However, if managers and customer contacts are not within the same domain it is probably better to add the person data twice - maybe the same person wants to have you different contact data as manager than as customer contact.

Part 2: You can choose what EF generates:
http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/code-first/inheritance-strategy-in-code-first.aspx

Comment: Good point. That wasn't a very good example. Maybe "CustomerContact" or something. The example was just made up for the question and don't reflect the actual entities I will be creating.

Comment: I'm not sure yet what kind of conflicting information you've got about inheritance yet, maybe I can add more specific information about part 1 of your question.

Answer (score 1):

From an object-oriented perspective, the problem with that approach is when a person becomes a manager, a employee, a vendor or all of them. In some latin languages we have to forms for the verb to be (ser/estar). The former refers to the nature of the being and later to the state. It is better to use isA for inheritances when refers to the nature of the being rather than its state. In your case, I would recommend using roles. A person has many roles. Manager is Role (Manager inherits from Role), Employee is Role, etc. This way, you can reuse your person attributes and you can add and remove roles of a person.